# Never cache js for development

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am using django runserver for development and I often find that the javascript file that I am using is being cached. It's almost impossible to tell when it's being cached unless I add alert or `console.log` statements every time I make a change to see if that's actually been "picked up".

Is there a setting in django to never cache the static files when running on localhost? Or is this something that has to do with my browser (Chrome) instead? What I am doing now as a hack, is each time I make a javascript change I change `v1` in my `script` tag.

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/settings.js?v1"></script>
```

Comment: you can simply disable cache in devtool's network tab in chrome

Comment: There's an option in DevTools settings to disable cache whenever DevTools is open.

Comment: you could also do something like `src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/settings.js?{{ CACHE_FLAG}}"`, where in dev you set the CACHE_FLAG var to a timestamp and in production you hard-code a real version number or build date, something static like that. this works on tablets et al that don't have devtools.

Comment: @dandavis oh that's great I love that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of dandavis, I created a context_processor variable:

```
def vars(request):
    return {
        'CACHE_FLAG': '1' if not settings.DEBUG else int(time.time()),
    }
```

Now in my template when I'm working in `DEBUG` mode it will prevent caching:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/settings.js?v{{ CACHE_FLAG }}"></script>
```